# Determine Mac driver that is associated with a device when knowing major and minor numbers

Tags: macos, kernel, driver, sysfs, readlink

Is there a way in Mac OS X that I can determine which device driver is associated with a particular device inside the /dev directory when device's major and minor numbers are known?

I have an FTDI device connected to my computer and need to know which driver will be used. Device's major and minor numbers are known:

```
cd /dev
ls -l | grep *usb*
```

and the output is:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 owner group 18, 8 Apr 7 12:29 tty.usbserial-A700eEsP
```

The 18, 8 tells us that major number is 18 and the minor is 8. Is there an equivalent to

```
 $ readlink /sys/dev/char/18\:8/device/driver
```

which can show me the driver that is associated with the device?

Comment: Untested, but something along the lines of `system_profiler -detailLevel full | grep -C10 -Ei "major|BSD"` maybe

Comment: Or maybe `ioreg -l`...